# Breadcrumbs + DropDown functionality

Tags: cms, extensions

Is there any extensions that would look like a breadcrumb + dropdown?

For ex a breadcrumb (path):

Home > Travel > Fly

When I hover on Travel => dropdown with all subitems from Travel:

- Fly
- Car
- etc.

Tried to search an extensions like that, but no success.

Comment: There are none that I know of either. Looks like you might have to develop something

Comment: I'd second @lodder. I would also make sure you use the schema breadcrumb markup if you do

Answer (score 1):

How comfortable are you with overrides?

Here's what I would do:

Create a menu module that shows the menu levels I want displayed in my breadcrumbs.

Use joomla's native breadcrumbs.

Create an override of the module (need instructions?).

At the bottom of the ul in the module, call in the menu module previously made. I'm not sure if loadposition will work here, but Modules Anywhere will for sure (that's a [No Number extension](http://www.nonumber.nl/)).

Then just style it up. Hide the menu module until the breadcrumb is hovered over, style them as desired, whatever works.

Why this way? Because you have 100% control. There's nothing more annoying than going through 30 plugins only to find each one doesn't quite fit the bill. Plus, the less plugins, the better. I prefer to use native joomla whenever possible.

Comment: you mean to call the menu module inside the breadcrumbs module? That means that the whole menu module will appear instead of a branch of the menu when I hover on a specific item of the breadcrumbs?

Comment: Well, no, you can select a level of the menu (ie. 2) and with css tell it when to show up when the right part is hovered. Menu module can tell what page you're on an pull the appropriate menu being used on that page (i.e. if you use the hidden menu, then when you're on a hidden menu page, you can call the sub menu items for that specific page). OR you can create an actually new menu for each section and call specific menus.

Comment: "you can select a level of the menu (ie. 2)" do you know how to do that? any reference or code? thanks

Comment: Open the Menu Module.  On the left hand side you select the menu you want to to use, eg. Main Menu, then you set your start level and end level. top level = 1, so if you wanted level 2 to show up, you'd change start level to 2 and your end level to 2.

Answer (score 0):

Why go trough hustle? Publish joomla menu module in breadcrumb position. Show all levels and add something like this  http://jsfiddle.net/5Lscg/.  Or use some of these 
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems